# justauth' reported an error of AuthRequestFactory' that could not be found

Tags: authentication

I'm trying to use justauth for third-party login authentication for Gitee, but I'm getting the following error.Parameter 0 of constructor in com.wy.springbootcomponent.justauth.JustAuthTestController required a bean of type 'com.xkcoding.justauth.AuthRequestFactory' that could not be found.

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.xkcoding.justauth</groupId>
            <artifactId>justauth-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.0</version>
        </dependency>

justauth:
  enabled: true
  type:
    GITEE:
      client-id: 46215e6e015a73e32e4e0a39773cc30b9734e845fb3144a016df45d1aa5b82b9
      client-secret: 6e40592e4dcc59adcd3fd61adc6af4e419104ee7a8d9208b2bb87e9891792c7f
      redirect-uri: http://oauth.xkcoding.com/demo/oauth/gitee/callback
  cache:
    type: default

@Slf4j
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/oauth")
@RequiredArgsConstructor(onConstructor_ = @Autowired)
public class JustAuthTestController {
    private final AuthRequestFactory factory;

    @GetMapping
    public List<String> list() {
        return factory.oauthList();
    }

    @GetMapping("/login/{type}")
    public void login(@PathVariable String type, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException, IOException {
        AuthRequest authRequest = factory.get(type);
        response.sendRedirect(authRequest.authorize(AuthStateUtils.createState()));
    }

    @RequestMapping("/{type}/callback")
    public AuthResponse login(@PathVariable String type, AuthCallback callback) {
        AuthRequest authRequest = factory.get(type);
        AuthResponse response = authRequest.login(callback);
        log.info("【response】= {}", JSONUtil.toJsonStr(response));
        return response;
    }

}
```